# copy DB from server using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, xampp

i have been created DB at server..i'm using XAMPP..how to copy the database from server PC using terminal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you

- [create a dump on the PC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)
- then you transfer that dump over to the other machine via `scp`
- [then you import the dump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html), see at the end of this link.